# Missing values in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to use "dropna" for "?" values in "Price" column in my dataset. But for some reason it is not working for me. It would be really helpful if someone could provide a solution to me on my dataset. I am providing all the syntax for fast input as well as the link to the file:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_csv(r"....",header=None)
headers=["Symboling","Normalized-losses","Make","Fuel-type","Aspiration","Num-of-doors","Body-style","Drive-wheels","Engine-location","Wheel-base","Length","Width","Height","Curb-weight","Engine-type","Num-of-cylinders","Engine-size","Fuel-system","Bore","Stroke","Compression-ratio","Horsepower","Peak-rpm","City-mpg","Highway-mpg","Price"]
df.columns=headers
df.dropna(subset=["Price"],axis=0,inplace=True)
```

File link: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/autos/imports-85.data

Comment: It's because `"?"` is not considered as a `NaN` (why would it be?). So if you were to drop rows conditionally, you can eithercreate a boolean array and select if condition met: `df[df["Price"].ne("?")]]`, or replace `"?"` to `NaN` then do `dropna`: `df.replace({"Price": "?"}, np.nan).dropna(subset=["Price"])`

Comment: You can alse replace the "?" values with np.nan and `df['Price'].replace("?", np.nan)` and then dropna

Answer (score 0):

"?" is not missing value - [See Values considered "missing"](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#values-considered-missing)

As the feature is numeric you can convert it to the numeric type first using [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with parameter `errors="coerce"` (To set value as `Nan` for invalid parsing.)

```
df["Price"] = pd.to_numeric(df.Price, errors="coerce")
```

And then you can use your solution to drop NaN
`df.dropna(subset=["Price"],axis=0,inplace=True)`

Comment: Glade it helps. If this solved your issue please consider to upvote or accept the answer. - https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235